# mypy: Can't get MYPYPATH to work in Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, mypy

I'm struggling to set MYPYPATH so that mypy will resolve modules that are not in the same directory as my main program. (It's fine if they are in the same directory).

I'm working in PowerShell on Windows 10. Full example below. Can anyone tell me the exact value I should set for MYPYPATH? I have tried every variant I can think of: relative path, absolute path, paths with '/' '\' and '\\'. I have read the mypy docs.

Here are my files:

```
C:\USERS\GARETH\MYPY
├───modules
│       utils.py
│
└───tests
        utils_test.py
```

utils.py:

```
def ff(x: str) -> str:
    return "Hello " + x
```

utils_test.py:

```
from modules.utils import ff

print(ff("world")) # OK
ff(42) # error
```

Here is my PowerShell session. Python finds the module and gives a runtime error (as expected):

```
PS C:\Users\Gareth\Mypy\tests> $env:PYTHONPATH
..
PS C:\Users\Gareth\Mypy\tests> python .\utils_test.py
Hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\utils_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    ff(42) # error
  File "C:\Users\Gareth\Mypy\modules\utils.py", line 3, in ff
    return "Hello " + x
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Whatever the value of MYPYPATH, mypy can't find the module:

```
PS C:\Users\Gareth\Mypy\tests> $env:MYPYPATH
..
PS C:\Users\Gareth\Mypy\tests> mypy .\utils_test.py
utils_test.py:1: error: Cannot find module named 'modules.utils'
utils_test.py:1: note: See 
https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
```

Can anyone please tell me the exact value I should set for MYPYPATH? This is the latest mypy:

```
PS C:\Users\Gareth\Mypy\tests> mypy --version
mypy 0.660
```

Comment: I don't have my Windows computer around to actually test this, but I suspect the problem has less to do with MYPYPATH and more because mypy by default has does not support for namespace modules (modules missing the `__init__.py` file). I would try repeating your MYPYPATH experiments after either adding a `modules/__init__.py` file or while using the `--namespace-packages` flag ([docs here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html)) and see if doing either helps.

Comment: @Michael0x2a Thanks Michael, adding the --namespace-packages flag works immediately! I did not know there was an issue with 'namespace modules'. It seems mypy is more picky than python itself about that. If you want to write this as an answer I will accept it. Cheers.

Comment: @Michael0x2a Putting an empty \_\_init\_\_.py in the modules directory also works.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question based on the comment provided by Michael0x2a.

In my example, the environment variable $env:MYPYPATH=".." works fine to import from modules.utils.

The problem is that MyPy is more picky than python itself about recognising .py files as modules. You must either put a file named __init__.py (which can be an empty file) in the modules directory, or run mypy with the --namespace-packages flag:

```
PS C:\Users\Gareth\Mypy\tests> mypy --namespace-packages .\utils_test.py
```